# Variable.1 unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic, netsh

I'm just trying to figure out why this block of code is giving me an unexpected variable..

```
@echo off
FOR /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%a IN (
    '"wmic nic where (MacAddress="00:00:00:00:00:00") GET NetConnectionId"'
) DO FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET nicName=%%b

echo Adding all IP ranges for X in 10.10.X.118 on adapter %nicName%
netsh interface ipv4 set address name=%nicName% static 192.168.1.118 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
FOR /L %A IN (0,1,255) DO netsh interface ipv4 add address %nicName% 10.10.%A%.118 255.255.255.0 10.10.%A%.1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver %nicName% address=208.67.222.222 index=1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver %nicName% address=208.67.220.220 index=2

exit
```

I think it has something to do with the first FOR loop interfering with the second, but I'm very new to using this type of search in a batch file.

The output I get is:

```
Adding all IP ranges for X in 10.10.X.118 on adapter Local Area Connection
nicNameAA.1 was unexpected at this time.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /L %A IN (0,1,255) DO netsh interface ipv4 add address %nicName% 10.10.%A%.118 255.255.255.0 10.10.%A%.1
```

1. As in the previous two `for` commands, the *metavariable* `A` must be specified as `%%A`.
2. As in the previous two `for` commands, the value substituted into the string must be specified as `%%A` - `%A%` is the value of an unspecified environment variable `A`.

The result of your code is this

```
FOR /L 
%A IN (0,1,255) DO netsh interface ipv4 add address %
nicName
% 10.10.%
A
%.118 255.255.255.0 10.10.%
A
%.1
```

each `%...%` is interpreted as a non-existent environment variable, hence it's replaced by *nothing*

So the code *appears* to be

```
FOR /L nicNameAA%.1
```

So `cmd` sees `nicNameAA%.1` where it's expecting `%%?` and complains.

BTW- since `nicname`'s value contains spaces, you probably need `"%nicname%"` so that `cmd` will see one string. Can't vouch for it since I rarely use `netsh`...just be prepared.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very well explained, and solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Magoo,
The resulting full code is as follows(In case anyone needs to do this in the future)

```
@echo off
FOR /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%a IN (
    '"wmic nic where (MacAddress="00:00:00:00:00:00") GET NetConnectionId"'
) DO FOR /F "Tokens=1" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET nicName=%%b

echo Adding all IP ranges for X in 10.10.X.118 on adapter "%nicName%"
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="%nicName%" static 192.168.1.118 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
FOR /L %%c IN (0,1,255) DO netsh interface ipv4 add address "%nicName%" 10.10.%%c.118 255.255.255.0 10.10.%%c.1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "%nicName%" address=208.67.222.222 index=1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "%nicName%" address=208.67.220.220 index=2

exit
```

Thanks again @Magoo!